# IsNumeric gives unexpected results in excel/vba for different regional settings

Tags: excel, vba, number-formatting, regional-settings

I had the impression that `IsNumeric(MyString)` would reveal if `Val(MyString)` is expected to fail or not. I have found unexpected differences depending on regional settings.

Example 1, Swedish regional settings (uses `,` as decimal separator):

- `IsNumeric("1.1")`=> True
- `Val("1.1")`=> 1.1
- `IsNumeric("1,1")`=> True
- `Val("1,1")`=> 1

Example 2, Estonian regional settings (also uses `,` as decimal separator):

- `IsNumeric("1.1")`=> **False**
- `Val("1.1")`=> 1.1
- `IsNumeric("1,1")`=> True
- `Val("1,1")`=> 1

My typical generic code for converting as string into a number is:

```
Function ConvertToNumber(MyNumber as String) as Double 
    If IsNumeric(MyNumber) then
        ConvertToNumber = Val(Replace(MyNumber, ",", "."))
    Else
        MsgBox "Invalid format!"
    End If
End Function
```

But this failed unexpectedly in Estonian regional settings. Any idea if this is the intended behavior?  Microsoft explanations on what IsNumber is doing is also a bit vague.  What do you suggest to use instead? `If Val(MyNumber & "1")<>0`? This would fail for some special cases such as `0E+0`. One could also consider catching any error from:

`CDbl(Replace(MyString, ".",  Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator))`

I could use regular expressions, but there must be better ways.

I would appreciate input on this.

/Jonas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is using the [Val function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/val-function) which does

> *Returns the numbers contained in a string as a numeric value of appropriate type.*

So it does not what you expet, because it does not **convert** a string into numbers but **extract** numbers contained in a string until the first non-numeric character that is not a whitespace.

That means

```
Val("    1615 198th Street N.E.")
```

will return `1615198` as double.

So what `Val` interprets as a decimal is always the `.` in all localizations. That means it will always cosider `Val("1.1")` as a number but in `Val("1,1")` the comma is the first non-numberic, non-whitespace character so it stops there and returns `1` only.

What you were looking for is the `CDbl` which actually **converts** a string into a number using the decimal seperator of your system.

```
Option Explicit

Function ConvertToNumber(ByVal MyNumber As String) As Double
    Dim RegionalNumber As String
    RegionalNumber = MyNumber
    
    ' if you want the user to be able to enter dots as well as commas
    ' make sure all dots and commas are converted to the decimal seperator of your system
    ' otherwise go without the conversion
    RegionalNumber = Replace$(RegionalNumber, ".", Application.DecimalSeparator)
    RegionalNumber = Replace$(RegionalNumber, ",", Application.DecimalSeparator)
    
    If IsNumeric(RegionalNumber) Then
        ConvertToNumber = CDbl(RegionalNumber)
    Else
        MsgBox "Invalid format!"
    End If
End Function
```

If you test this with

```
Sub test() 
    Debug.Print ConvertToNumber("1.1")
    Debug.Print ConvertToNumber("1,1")
End Sub
```

on a system where comma is the decimal seperator it should both times return `1,1` as a number.

---

#### Explanation why your tests returned the results they returned

Example 1, Swedish regional settings (uses ',' as decimal separator):

- `IsNumeric("1.1")`=> True
  Because `.` is considered as date seperator so it is a valid number
- `Val("1.1")`=> 1.1
  Because val always considers dot as decimal separator
- `IsNumeric("1,1")`=> True
  Because `,` is considered as **decimal** seperator
- `Val("1,1")`=> 1
  Because val always considers comma as non-numeric character

Example 2, Estonian regional settings (also uses ',' as decimal separator):

- `IsNumeric("1.1")`=> **False**
  Because dot in estonian is **not** considered date seperator this is not a valid number
- `Val("1.1")`=> 1.1
  Because val always considers dot as decimal separator
- `IsNumeric("1,1")`=> True
  Because `,` is considered as decimal seperator
- `Val("1,1")`=> 1
  Because val always considers comma as non-numeric character

Note that `IsNumeric` accepts thousand seperators, date seperators and decimal seperators as well as currency symbols.

Comment: Thanks for this. However, I still do not understand what "IsNumeric" is doing exactly. Why does it give "True" for the string "1.1" in Swedish regional settings where Application.DecimalSeparator = ","?

Comment: There is still something fishy here. In *both* Swedish and *Estonian* regional settings asc(Application.ThousandsSeparator) = 160 (nonbreaking space) and asc(Application.International(xlThousandsSeparator)) = 32 (space). There is no "." as thousand separator.

Comment: @j74nilsson that is strange. I cannot test it here as I'm on german Excel. But test the result of `CDbl("1,1")` and `CDbl("1.1")` then, does both work?

Comment: Strangly Cdbl("1.1") gives "11" on Swedish and "Run time error 13, type mismatch" on Estonian. For some reason "." seems to be working as a thousand separator in swedish Cdbl/IsNumeric although it shouldn't.

Comment: Ahh got it `IsNumeric` also returns `True` if the string can be considered as a valid date. Check the date formats on both! Reading the documentation helped here!

Comment: I think we will close the comments with this: I found the issue. It was not "date" but "currency digit grouping symbol" that was set to ".". When this was modified Cdbl fails also in Swedish regional settings.

Comment: @j74nilsson well finally we figured out. The improtant thing is whenever `IsNumeric` considers it as a number then `CDbl` should be able to convert it into a double. While `Val` does not.

Answer (score 0):

**Unfortunately,** I am not familiar with getting around those particular regional settings to work with the built-in function `IsNumeric()`. But **fortunately,** I can help you create your own customized function with the help of Regular Expressions.

You can utilize the below function. Once you've added it to a standard code module, just use `IsNumber("1.1")` instead of `IsNumeric("1.1")`.

```
Function IsNumber(ByVal TestString As Variant) As Boolean

    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    
        .Pattern = "^(?:\d+[.,]?\d*|\d*[.,]\d+)$"
        IsNumber = .test(TestString)
        
    End With
        
End Function
```

[image]

Now of course, if someone else comes in with a more direct approach, I'd recommend using that method. However, this should work for you otherwise.

---

Let's break down the pattern `^(?:\d+[.,]?\d*|\d*[.,]\d+)$` real quick. This pattern has an OR operator, which is the `|` symbol, so we will review them separately.

- `^` asserts that this is the start of your string.
- `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group. This is just so we don't have to add start of string `^` and end of string `$` anchors to each of the OR `|` statements.
- `\d+` matches any numerical character `\d`, one or more times `+`, then immediately is followed by
- `[.,]?` is a character group that will match any character in that group, **zero** or **one** times `?` (making it optional), then immediately followed by
- `\d*`, which will match any digit `\d`, **zero** or **more** times `*` (essentially making it optional, but can have unlimited characters)
- and finally, we have the end of string anchor `$`

The second part of the OR statement is essentially the same, but I made the first `\d` optional to allow for things such as `.1` (notice no number in front of the `.`) to still match as numeric.

---

With everything said, this would now allow you to update your code to:

```
Function ConvertToNumber(MyNumber as String) as Double 
    If IsNumber(MyNumber) then
        'Your code
    Else
        'Your code
    End If
End Function
```

Although if it were my code, I'd check for numeric value prior to sending to your conversion function:

```
If IsNumber(MyNumber) Then
    Debug.Print ConvertToNumber(MyNumber)
Else
    'Handle it here
End If
```

Although it doesn't really make much of a difference, this makes more since to me personally.

Comment: RegExp is ofcourse an option. It could be expanded to include scientific notation: ^\d+([.,]\d+)?([eEdD][+-]?\d+)?$

Comment: Actually there is no need to use that overhead of a RegEx because `IsNumeric` is doing a great job if you stick to the decimal and thousands operators of your system. Then it does exactly what it is intendet to do. Just `Val` is evil, because it does **not** turn a string into a number as the OP assumed, it does extract numeric characters out of a string and that is something entirely differnt as I showed in my answer.

Comment: Not really. See my post where IsNumber("1.1") returns true even on swedish regional settings where the decimal separator is ","

Comment: @j74nilsson Please check my explanations again. In swedish the dot is considered a thousands separator but not in estonian I guess. So in swedish you can write `1.100,35` and this is a valid number. But not in estonian. The issue is `Val` not `IsNumeric`.